# Yii Return Url with query string

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I want to create a button, that when is clicked, it will navigate to the previous page.
I am using bootstrap theme, and what I've done so far is :

```
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
    'label'=>'Back',
    'type'=>'action',
    'size'=>'normal',
    'url'=>Yii::app()->user->returnUrl
)); ?>
```

But this seems only to create the button that goes to previous URL but without the query string. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just refer here:

[yii-way-to-get-the-previous-url](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/11959-any-yii-way-to-get-the-previous-url/)

Yii Provides good way to do this

```
Yii::app()->request->urlReferrer
```